# Why my insertion sort code is not working? It is giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I am trying to do *insertion sort* but it is not working properly.
I am doing as per the requirements and it is still giving error.
Any suggestions or any advice on what I am doing wrong.
kindly help, I am new to programming.

```java
package practicepkg;

public class InsertionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {10, 2, 3, 45, 66};

        int count = 1, temp = 0;
        int i, j, key;
        for (j = count; j < 4; j++) {
            key = j;
            if (key < 4 && temp < 4) {
                for (i = temp; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (a[key] < a[i]) {
                        int n = a[key];
                        a[key] = a[i];
                        a[i] = n;
                    }
                    key++;
                }
                temp++;
                count++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            System.out.println("Sorted array is " + a[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
>     at practicepkg.InsertionDemo.main(InsertionDemo.java:17)

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning key to the value of j which should be assigned the value of `a[j]`.
Further replace the sizes with 5 or size of array along with elimination of count and temp variables.
Your corrected code is here:

```java
public class InsertionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {10, 2, 3, 66, 45};
        int i, j, key;
        for (j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
            key = a[j];
            for (i = j - 1; (i >= 0 && a[i] > key); i--) {
                a[i + 1] = a[i];
            }
            a[i + 1] = key;
        }
        for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
            System.out.println("Sorted array is " + a[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey , thanks for helping . in this line `f(key<a.length&&temp<a.length)` if we are asigning key the vales then it will always yield true . this code when i entered more values it is not sorting anymore . I mean it is sorting till 5th element, I tried yours . Any help?

Comment: Hey @user9685761 The array elements are sorted only, in case you add more elements to array, you'll have to increment the size of array in code. So better use **a.length** to get the size. Rest of your code is fine.
In case it is correct answer, please accept the answer.

Comment: Hi , I tried your code. It is still not sorting anything. It is printing as it is. I am stuck on it from past two days. Kindly help.

Comment: Dear @user9685761, in no way it is my code. It was about the mistakes you were doing. Also there is no need of count and temp variable, you're using count in j and incrementing both count and j, so j is incremented with it's own. Similar is the case with temp. So, better to do it without them. Check my edited answer, and you're doing good. Keep it up.

Comment: hey,Thankyou for the help and for your kind words.